# What's the difference between a Bayes Estimator and a Maximum a posteriori (MAP) Estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have been practicing with two textbooks and one has a chapter on Bayes Estimator (Sheldon Ross) and another has a Chapter on MAP Estimation (Pishro Nik).
I seem to get the same answers (to the simple Example Problems) using either and it looks like the process is the same, but I feel like there is some difference, I just can't pin it down.

Could someone explain it to me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bayesian Statistic there are different kind of estimators for a parameter. Different estimators come out because of different hypothesis about the loss function.

Here are some examples:

1. an estimator which minimize Mean Square Error, that is posterior expectation
2. MAP, Maximum a Posteriori, the estimator which maximize posterior density
3. Posterior Median
4. Posterior Mode

---

**Consider the following example:**

---

Throwing a coin, we are intersted in estimating the parameter $\theta$: probability to get Head.

We have no information *"a Priori"* about the parameter's value thus the prior is uniform

$$\pi(\theta)=1$$

Suppose we flip the coin 10 times getting 6 H and 4T thus the posterior is

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \theta^6(1-\theta)^4$$

that is a $\text{Beta}(7;5)$, thus

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})=2310\cdot\theta^6(1-\theta)^4$$

Depending on which estimator we want to use we get

$$\hat{\theta}_{\text{MMSE}}=\mathbb{E}\left[\theta|\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{7}{12}$$

$$\hat{\theta}_{\text{MAP}}=\frac{6}{10}$$

Comment: Oh, so the MAP is a Bayes Estimator? But just one of many?

Comment: @oliver: yes, exactly. In the above example I showed two bayesian estimators. Sheldon Ross is a good textbook but not exactly a Bayesian textbook

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. I have down mc elrath in part and the kruschke book, I'm quite interested in Bayesian Data Analysis but would love some more theoretical books to build intuition. If you have any recommends please let me know.